# Pandas output date, start and end time and event status given datetime continuity

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following dataframe:

```
                    Site
       Date
2021-07-01 08:00:00  54
2021-07-01 09:00:00  23
2021-07-01 10:00:00  13
2021-07-01 11:00:00  23
2021-07-01 15:00:00  345
2021-07-01 16:00:00  313
2021-07-05 08:00:00  3
2021-07-05 09:00:00  31
2021-07-13 08:00:00  76
2021-07-13 09:00:00  34
2021-07-13 10:00:00  94
2021-07-13 11:00:00  55
2021-07-13 12:00:00  43
2021-07-13 13:00:00  423
2021-07-13 14:00:00  231
2021-07-13 15:00:00  23
2021-07-13 16:00:00  563
2021-07-13 17:00:00  424
```

I am trying to get the date, start and end time of an event. The condition is such that:

1. If there is no break in time continuity (like 2021-07-13), from
   `08:00:00` to `17:00:00` is a full day event
2. If time continuity break and is not continuous like 2021-07-13, it will be an incomplete day event

The end result is this:

```
                Start       End      Result
   Date        
2021-07-01   08:00:00   11:00:00   Incomplete
2021-07-01   15:00:00   16:00:00   Incomplete
2021-07-05   08:00:00   09:00:00   Incomplete
2021-07-13   08:00:00   17:00:00      Full
```

Is there an easy way to perform this operation in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#if necessary convert to DatetimeIndex
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

#create column Date
df = df.reset_index()

#test consecutive hours
df['g'] = df['Date'].diff().dt.total_seconds().div(3600).ne(1)

date = df['Date'].dt.date
#created groups
df['g'] = df.groupby(date)['g'].cumsum()

#get minimal and maximal per dates
df1 = (df.groupby([date, 'g'])
         .agg(Start=('Date','min'),End=('Date','max'))
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))

#convert to HH:MM:SS
df1['Start'] = df1['Start'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df1['End'] = df1['End'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

#result column
df1['Result'] = np.where(df1['Start'].eq('08:00:00') & 
                         df1['End'].eq('17:00:00'), 'Full','Incomplete')
print (df1)
               Start       End      Result
Date                                      
2021-07-01  08:00:00  11:00:00  Incomplete
2021-07-01  15:00:00  16:00:00  Incomplete
2021-07-05  08:00:00  09:00:00  Incomplete
2021-07-13  08:00:00  17:00:00        Full
```

Alternative with `time`s:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df = df.reset_index()

df['g'] = df['Date'].diff().dt.total_seconds().div(3600).ne(1)

date = df['Date'].dt.date
df['g'] = df.groupby(date)['g'].cumsum()

df1 = (df.groupby([date, 'g'])
         .agg(Start=('Date','min'),End=('Date','max'))
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
df1['Start'] = df1['Start'].dt.time
df1['End'] = df1['End'].dt.time

from datetime import time

df1['Result'] = np.where(df1['Start'].eq(time(8,0,0)) & 
                         df1['End'].eq(time(17,0,0)), 'Full','Incomplete')
print (df1)
               Start       End      Result
Date                                      
2021-07-01  08:00:00  11:00:00  Incomplete
2021-07-01  15:00:00  16:00:00  Incomplete
2021-07-05  08:00:00  09:00:00  Incomplete
2021-07-13  08:00:00  17:00:00        Full
```